# How to extract multiple column names having max values in python dataframe?

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a dataframe similar to the following. I am trying to extract multiple column names that has max value in the row.

```
import pandas as pd
data = [['rama', 10, 20, 20,12], ['radha', 15, 18, 12, 18], ['sai', 14, 12, 10, 11]] 
ex_df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['name','sub1','sub2','sub3','sub4'])
ex_df.iloc[:,1:].apply('idxmax', axis=1)
```

The above code gives me `'sub2', 'sub2', 'sub1'` as output. But I require the output to be `['sub2','sub3'], ['sub2','sub4'], ['sub1']` as output. Is there any method to extract multiple column names that has max value in the row?

Comment: Shouldn't be `['sub2','sub3'], ['sub3'], ['sub1']` ? Can you *double-check* your expected output ?

Comment: I have edited the question. Basically, I need column names that have max values.

Comment: So why row 2 and 3 should have `['sub2','sub4']` and `'sub1'` respectively ?

Comment: data = [['rama', 10, 20, 20,12], ['radha', 15, 18, 12, 18], ['sai', 14, 12, 10, 11]] This is the edit. So, ['sub2','sub4'] for row 2. And ['sub1'] for row 3.

Comment: Ok, then the answers below should work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one option with [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html)/[*boolean indexing*](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) :

```
subs = ex_df.filter(like="sub")

ser = subs.apply(lambda x: x.index[x.eq(x.max())].tolist(), axis=1)

out = ex_df[["name"]].join(ser.rename("max_cols"))
```

Output :

```
print(out)

    name      max_cols
0   rama  [sub2, sub3]
1  radha  [sub2, sub4]
2    sai        [sub1]
```

*Input used :*

```
    name  sub1  sub2  sub3  sub4
0   rama    10    20    20    12
1  radha    15    18    12    18
2    sai    14    12    10    11
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the boolean matrix if row value is the max in that row. Then stack to find the column name that matches the True.

```py
cols = df.filter(like='sub').columns
#
cols = df.columns.difference(['name'])

out = (df[cols].eq(df[cols].max(axis=1), axis=0)
       .stack().loc[lambda s: s]
       .groupby(level=0)
       .apply(lambda s: s.index.get_level_values(1).tolist())
       .tolist())
```

```
print(out)

[['sub2', 'sub3'], ['sub2', 'sub4'], ['sub1']]
```

Or you can do with matrix manipulation

```
m = df[cols].eq(df[cols].max(axis=1), axis=0)

out = ((m.columns * m)
       .stack().loc[lambda s: s.ne('')]
       .groupby(level=0).agg(list)
       .tolist())
```

```
print(m)

    sub1   sub2   sub3   sub4
0  False   True   True  False
1  False   True  False   True
2   True  False  False  False
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df_max = ex_df.iloc[:, 1:].apply('max', axis=1)
df_mask_max = ex_df.iloc[:, 1:].eq(df_max, axis=0)
[(x, df_mask_max.columns[y]) for x,y in np.argwhere(df_mask_max.values)]
```

This returns `[(0, 'sub2'), (0, 'sub3'), (1, 'sub2'), (1, 'sub4'), (2, 'sub1')]`

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, "idxmax" is a special function which is well documented in pandas documentation here:

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html

You can look at their code to maybe try to have a `custom_idxmax()` function that can return not just the first instance, but multiple instances of max if found, then use that function in your `df.apply()`.

https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/455c880ddbe738074cf87f8a99266646a9855386/pandas/core/series.py

However, I would propose a more straightforward solution by iterating your dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
data = [['rama', 10, 20, 20,12], ['radha', 15, 18, 12, 18], ['sai', 14, 12, 10, 11]]
ex_df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['name','sub1','sub2','sub3','sub4'])

final_results = []
for i, row in ex_df.iterrows():
    values = row.iloc[1:]
    max_value = values.max()
    results = list(row[row==max_value].index)
    final_results.append(results)
```

You should get your desired output:

```
final_results=[['sub2', 'sub3'], ['sub2', 'sub4'], ['sub1']]
```

Comment: I strongly discourage to loop on the rows in this way